# How to enable horizontal scroll using middle touch button of Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors, blackberry-webworks

I developed an app with jquery mobile ,but I want to scroll the content inside   using the middle touch button of device. Currently I can scroll the page vertically but not horizontatly.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your page width to a value above 100%.

*Not much else can be done to help you without posting code/what you've tired.*